# Flot Graph not rendering properly in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, flot

I am using Flot Graphs and they are plotting fine. But in firefox v33, on redrawing multiple times black rectangles are appearing. My options:

```
var lineChartOptions = {
        series : {
            lines : {
                show : true
            },
            points : {
                show : true
            },
            shadowSize : 3
        },
        grid : {
            hoverable : true //IMPORTANT! this is needed for tooltip to work
        },
        yaxis : {
            tickDecimals : 0,
            min : 0,
            max : 100
        },
        xaxes : [ {
            mode : "time",
            timeformat : "%d/%m/%y"
        }],

        tooltip : true,
        tooltipOpts : {
            content : "%y activations on %x",
            shifts : {
                x : -60,
                y : 25
            }
        }
    };
```

On Ajax call:

```
var axes = plotObj.getAxes();
           axes.yaxis.options.max = null;
           plotObj.setData(graph_json);
           plotObj.setupGrid();
           plotObj.draw();
```

[image]

It replicates when Y-Axis value goes from a lower to higher value. For the following set of data on three ajax calls in the order mentioned:

```
[{"data":[["2014-11-02",5],["2014-11-03",2],["2014-11-04",2]],"label":"Skype","color":8}]

[{"data":[["2014-10-01",0],["2014-10-31",0]],"label":"Skype","color":8}]

[{"data":[["2014-09-03",1],["2014-11-02",5],["2014-11-03",2],["2014-11-04",2]],"label":"Skype","color":8}]
```

Comment: can you give a demo of it jsfiddle? so we can check that in firefox

Comment: attach options please

Answer (score 0):

This occured due to follpwing line:

```
axes.yaxis.options.max = null;
```

I tried using this as a workaround to make flot calculate the new maximum for Y-Axis itself after setting it in the options. But it seems to cause rendering issues